# Why does Windows delete 0 byte file on flashdrive instead of 944MB?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I'm getting a strange thing when trying to delete a file on my USB flash drive.
Windows tells the operation will delete a 0-byte file while the actual file is 966 805 504 bytes.

[image]

[image]

Is that a sign of near-dead USB flash drive, or a simple display bug?

Comment: Please provide an English translation to your screenshots